# Google App Script publicado como una aplicación web no funciona

Tags: google-apps-script

Realice un formulario con una respuesta geolocalizada, sin embargo al momento de responder el formulario desde celular me da error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí que el problema se debía por tener varias sesiones de google abiertas, pero cerre todas y me quede solo con la que estaba trabajando y tampoco soluciono el problema

Comment: En ocaciones el servidor de google se satura y muestra archivos no encontrados.